# Incorrect values of the optimal solution

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm trying to solve a linear optimization
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5LLN.png)
In my case, K is 2 and p1, p2 are all 0.5, n=8 and m=5.
Specifically, the full formula of the problem is
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RTt1.png)
with the [constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTcny.png)
For simplicity, because K in this problem is small so I don't need to create a matrix for it. Instead, I declare separate variables, which are y1, y2, z1, z2, d1, and d2. All the variables are assumed to be non-negative.

I attempted to solve this problem using pyomo in python.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.AbstractModel()

model.n = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)
model.m = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)

model.I = pyo.RangeSet(model.n)
model.J = pyo.RangeSet(model.m)

model.c = pyo.Param(model.J)
model.a = pyo.Param(model.I, model.J)
model.l = pyo.Param(model.I)
model.q = pyo.Param(model.I)
model.s = pyo.Param(model.J)
model.d_1 = pyo.Param(model.I)
model.d_2 = pyo.Param(model.I)

model.x = pyo.Var(model.J, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.y_1 = pyo.Var(model.J, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.z_1 = pyo.Var(model.I, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

model.y_2 = pyo.Var(model.J, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.z_2 = pyo.Var(model.I, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def obj_expression(m):
    return sum(m.c[j]*m.x[j] for j in m.J) + 0.5*(sum((m.l[i]-m.q[i])*m.z_1[i] for i in m.I) - sum(m.s[j]*m.y_1[j] for j in m.J)) + 0.5*(sum((m.l[i]-m.q[i])*m.z_2[i] for i in m.I) - sum(m.s[j]*m.y_2[j] for j in m.J))
    
model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_expression, sense=pyo.minimize)

def constraint1_rule(m, j):
    return m.y_1[j] == m.x[j] - sum(m.a[i,j]*m.z_1[i] for i in m.I)
def constraint2_rule(m, j):
    return m.y_2[j] == m.x[j] - sum(m.a[i,j]*m.z_2[i] for i in m.I)

def constraint3_rule(m, i):
    return m.z_1[i] <= m.d_1[i]
def constraint4_rule(m, i):
    return m.z_2[i] <= m.d_2[i]

model.AxbConstraint1 = pyo.Constraint(model.J, rule=constraint1_rule)
model.AxbConstraint2 = pyo.Constraint(model.J, rule=constraint2_rule)
model.AxbConstraint3 = pyo.Constraint(model.I, rule=constraint3_rule)
model.AxbConstraint4 = pyo.Constraint(model.I, rule=constraint4_rule)

data = pyo.DataPortal()
data.load(filename="abstract2.dat", model = model)
instance = model.create_instance(data)

optimizer = pyo.SolverFactory("glpk")
optimizer.solve(instance)

instance.display()
```

My ".dat" file looks like this:

```
param n := 8 ;
param m := 5 ;
param c :=
1 35
2 12
3 6
4 94
5 2
;
param l :=
1 21
2 82
3 87
4 81
5 39
6 10
7 52
8 49
;
param q :=
1 99
2 96
3 95
4 91
5 87
6 89
7 81
8 69
;
param s :=
1 13
2 7
3 4
4 13
5 1
;
param a :=
1 1 0
1 2 2
1 3 2
1 4 3
1 5 2
2 1 9
2 2 4
2 3 1
2 4 9
2 5 4
3 1 7
3 2 0
3 3 0
3 4 0
3 5 3
4 1 1
4 2 8
4 3 2
4 4 1
4 5 8
5 1 5
5 2 6
5 3 1
5 4 9
5 5 1
6 1 6
6 2 1
6 3 5
6 4 8
6 5 4
7 1 7
7 2 8
7 3 7
7 4 5
7 5 1
8 1 2
8 2 0
8 3 9
8 4 9
8 5 4
;
param d_1 :=
1 6
2 5
3 5
4 6
5 7
6 4
7 4
8 3
;
param d_2 :=
1 6
2 5
3 4
4 6
5 4
6 4
7 5
8 7
;
```

However, when I ran this code, the solutions to all the variables were 0, resulting in the function value 0, which makes it seem very illogical and nonsense. I have tried different inputs but the result was still the same.

Comment: seems like the correct solution to me....  You should be inspecting the result by catching the result of the solve and inspecting it (it shows optimal, which is good).  It is a minimization problem, and 0 is pretty low.  :).  If `l-q` is negative (it is in your case), and `s` is positive, this could "go negative" if `z` and/or `y` were "high", but they are limited by the constraint with `x` and `cx` tends to be a *large* positive number, which outweighs any possible negativity.  Reduce `c` in your data and the problem quickly becomes unbounded